# Please suggest any automation testing tool for IVR(Interactive Voice Response) testing?

Tags: automation, ivr

I am looking for the automation of IVR process and scenario. Did some google search but did not get any good solution. My preference is Open Source and can be integrate with Java. If any paid tool also exist which have high capability of function and performance automation then also it will work for me.
Please suggest.

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use an Asterisk with a specific scenario, or SIPP in you use VoIP.
If you need to develop complex interactions with voice or DTMF, the standard dialplan or AGI could be boring... We had develop a free Asterisk Dialer script to apply a constant charge. Let me know if you need it.

Comment: Thanks for replying! It will be very helpful if you share a sample script of Asterisk or any tutorial site for the same.